# Azure DevOps build of Xamarin.iOS project fails - MTOUCH : error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Drawing.Color" reference

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

I have a build issue with a Xamarin.iOS app in Azure DevOps that I haven't been able to solve. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Building the iOS version of the app works locally in VS for Mac but fails in Azure due to this error:

`MTOUCH : error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Drawing.Color" reference from "System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [/Users/runner/runners/2.164.6/work/1/s/iOS/CatRentalStore.iOS.csproj]`

I was having a similar issue with the Android build. I resolved it by switching from the macOS-10.14 hosted build agent to the windows-2019 agent, but that isn't an option with the iOS app.

I've updated packages that may use System.Drawing.Color to the latest stable releases - Acr.UserDialogs, BTProgressHUD, Splat, and Xamarin.Essentials.

I searched the solution source and did not find any direct references to the System.Drawing.Color class.

I also tried specifying the version of Xamarin/Mono to use in the build to match my local version using `sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 6_4_0`. That caused a different error to occur:

```
error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
error MSB4018: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageDependency> NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFileTargetLibrary.get_Dependencies()
```

References to this issue:

https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/13483

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/6011

https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/654

https://github.com/reactiveui/splat/issues/204

Comment: I can't reproduce same issue, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer#net-core): .NET Core 2.2.105 is default on VM images but Mono version 6.0 or greater requires .NET Core 2.2.300+. If you use the Mono 6.0 or greater, you will have to override .NET Core version using .NET Core Tool Installer task. If you use 6.4.0, you need to install at least 2.2.300+ .net core. May it help.

Comment: @ToBeOrNotToBe - specifying the .NET Core version fixed the issue. THANK YOU for sharing that info! I had read the page you linked to but had somehow missed the .NET Core info.

Comment: Glad to know it makes some help. If it resolves your issue, you can consider accepting it as answer. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer#net-core):

NET Core `2.2.105` is default on VM images but Mono version 6.0 or greater requires .NET Core `2.2.300+`. If you use the Mono 6.0 or greater, you will have to override .NET Core version using [.NET Core Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops). If you use 6.4.0, you need to install at least 2.2.300+ .net core.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Visual Studio sometimes failed to update the reference during the NuGet package upgrade:

These steps helped me resolve my issue (iOS project):

- Check every reference and see if it matches the version of the corresponding NuGet package

  - Check the path/version of the referenced assembly: [image: make sure that versions match]
  - Make sure that it matches your installed package version: [image]
- If the versions do not match: downgrade the corresponding NuGet package and then upgrade the same NuGet package again and check if the version now matches

I did that procedure one NuGet package at a time. After ensuring that all versions match the build succeeded.

On my dev machine, the older versions were still present in the packages folder. Therefore the build always worked on my machine but not on the build server.